# Image upload button on overlay...having issues with my css

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm having a slight issue with centering the content of an overlay - for some reason I can't get this to work.

html:

```
<div class="avatar-container">
  <img src="{% static 'img/oauth/avatar_placeholder.svg' %}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle avatar-image" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
  <div class="avatar-overlay">
    <div class="avatar-overlay__text">
      <input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" width="30px"/>
      <input type="file" id='upload_image' name="{{ userprofile_form.user_avatar.name }}" {% if userprofile_form.user_avatar.value %}value="{{ userprofile_form.user_avatar.value }}"{% endif %} style="display: none;" />
      <div>Upload Image</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.avatar-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.avatar-image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.avatar-overlay {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.avatar-container:hover .avatar-image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.avatar-container:hover .avatar-overlay  {
  opacity: 1;
}

.avatar-overlay__text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

js:

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
  $("input[id='upload_image']").click();
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/michealjroberts/L8cwc1of/

Could anyone advise how I can get the image (upload button) and the text as outlined in the above jsfiddle to be aligned as centrally as possible...

Comment: If you mean aligned in the center as a column then just add text-align: center on the .avatar-overlay__text class https://jsfiddle.net/L8cwc1of/1/

Comment: @Julian Espinosa - it looks like you were using an older version of the jsfiddle - my apologies. I have updated it - with your suggestions, and unfortunately it does't work. However, what you stated seemed to work on what was there before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following code to CSS:

```
.avatar-overlay__text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
}
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/L8cwc1of/16/

I just add the above CSS code at the end of CSS section of fiddle.

Comment: Nope dude, it will work for following:

OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7,  TWEENER - IE 10,  NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10, NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera.

Comment: Will look to implement this stuff and do some testing before I accept answer.

Comment: Sure, kool deal :)

Comment: Yeh tested this using the Turbo browser sandbox and haven't found anything broken as yet. Awesome stuff.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/L8cwc1of/4/

I gave the button image an id, then set it to `float: center;`, along with Julian's comment to add `text-align: center;` on the containing div.

Comment: float: center ? really ??

Comment: Yeh tried that - it doesn't work. Tried it on my updated jsfiddle - doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code snippet below and let me know if this is what you want.

I have wrapped the upload button HTML in a div (class image-container) and made it appear in the center of the div, using

```
.image-container{
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```js
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
  $("input[id='upload_image']").click();
});
```

```css
.avatar-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.avatar-image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.avatar-overlay {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.avatar-container:hover .avatar-image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.avatar-container:hover .avatar-overlay  {
  opacity: 1;
}

.avatar-overlay__text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="avatar-container">
  <img src="{% static 'img/oauth/avatar_placeholder.svg' %}" alt="User Avatar" class="img-responsive img-circle avatar-image" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
  <div class="avatar-overlay">
    <div class="avatar-overlay__text">
    <div class='image-container'>
      <input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" width="30px"/>
      <input type="file" id='upload_image' name="{{ userprofile_form.user_avatar.name }}" {% if userprofile_form.user_avatar.value %}value="{{ userprofile_form.user_avatar.value }}"{% endif %} style="display: none;" />
      <div>Upload Image</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps